# What does it mean if the Fisher information matrix in block diagonal form for the parameter estimation?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, estimation, fisher-information

If for a given problem the fisher information matrix is diagonal or block diagonal, from the estimation point of view, what does it mean?

Does it mean, for 2 parameters in different blocks, the estimation can be done independently?
Searching for one and then for the other?

To be concrete, assume a model with 2 parameters.
We can build a grid for searching the optimal value (Be it the general likelihood or even say gaussian case so the least squares).
Let's say we do grid search over `MxN` points.
So in the general case we need to go over all those `MxN` points.
Can we, if the 2 parameters don't share the same block on the fisher information matrix, search for the first one over `M` points and then for the second one over `N` points?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "estimation done independently." It does indicate the parameter estimates are uncorrelated between blocks.  That follows immediately from the fact that the inverse of a block diagonal matrix is also block diagonal.

Comment: @whuber, In case of 2 parameters, does it means that instead of doing a search over `MxN` points I can do search over `M+N`?

Comment: I don't understand: how are searches involved in examining an information matrix?

Comment: @whuber, I am after how it affects the optimization. Namely if it's the case, can I solve each problem on its own?

Comment: Optimization of what?  You seem to have some unstated context in mind, because the Fisher information matrix is a mathematical construct that often is computed directly.  You also seem to be conceiving of estimating parameters as somehow being a collection of unrelated problems, but it rarely is, even when those parameters are uncorrelated.  A standard example is estimating the coefficients in an ordinary regression whose explanatory variable has been centered: the Fisher information matrix is diagonal for Normal responses.

Comment: @whuber, I am trying to understand what does the blog diagonal structure can tell in the process of solving the parameter estimation phase and not only what it says about the behavior of the estimator, assuming it is asymptotically efficient.

Comment: You seem to have a particular algorithm in mind as well as some particular model.  Your questions don't generally make sense because there are many algorithms for fitting MLEs and infinitely many possible models.  Could you therefore provide some information about your model and algorithm?

Comment: @whuber, No specific algorithm. I'd even say the most simple one. A grid search. Can I do the grid search independently for 2 parameters not sharing the same block?

Comment: The information matrix tells you nothing about that, which is why this conversation is mystifying.  It's only *local* information in the neighborhood of the global maximum.  Unless perhaps we have different understandings of what this matrix is.  I realize it can refer to the variance of the score at any parameter value, but then it's hard to conceive of any situation where that is always block diagonal: my understanding is that you are asking about the matrix at the maximum likelihood estimate.

Comment: @whuber, If it has no effect, that's the answer. Could you post it as an answer and I will mark it?